# Github see number of issues I've closed all time

Tags: git, github

Is there any way I can see how many issues I've closed since the beginning of time on GitHub?

Answer (score 2):

It is best to check the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)

For instance, the [List Issues API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues) can List all issues across owned and member repositories assigned to the authenticated user:

```
GET /user/issues
```

And you can filter by state, which include "`closed`".

If you have many issues, do mind [the pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination).

Comment: This doesn't account for tickets you don't have permission to access anymore, eg a company i worked at and no longer have access to their git repo. Also I might not even be assigned to the ticket, but I might have been the one that closed it.

Comment: @Minimi I agree, this is not a query with exhaustive result. Although if you have no longer access to a repo, not having access to the issue seems a logical consequence.